# Nextjs app cannot build using shared library as part of a monorepo

Tags: next.js, pnpm

I have a monorepo with pnpm and I have backend, and 3 nextjs apps that connect to that backend in the monorepo

```
/packages
         /admin -> nextjs
         /operator -> nextjs
         /backend -> nestjs
         /shared -> shared library
```

I am having a problem in the operator web page, I am trying to export some functions that might be used in the other projects. But functions that are part of the frontend in reactjs I get the following:
[image]

It is linking to the project as "../shared/..." so it is going down one folder to link it so that is why I think that is why webpack has a trouble bundling the shared library.

[image]

This is what it shows on the pnpm-lock.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out,
I was really dumb
I was adding my libraries like this

```
import { apiRequest } from "shared/utils/apiRequest";
```

And my index.ts in my library

```
export default {
  ...
  apiRequest,
  ...
};
```

I fixed the exports on src/index.ts

```
import { apiRequest } from "shared";
```

Exports in my index.ts removed default

```
export {
  ...
  apiRequest,
  ...
};
```